# Flutter video_thumbnail "Couldn't generate thumbnail" on IOS

Tags: flutter, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I'm using the `video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3` flutter package to present the video's first frame.

Here is my code:

```
Future<Uint8List?> generateThumbnail(String videoUrl) async {
  try {
    final thumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(video: 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4');
    return thumbnail;
  } catch (e) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Error generating thumbnail: $e');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to load a list of thumbnails (even from the same URL), but on old IOS devices most of them are not loaded, and I'm getting the above error.

> couldn't generate thumbnail, error:Error
> Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be
> completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error
> occurred (-12792), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be
> completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x283be6730 {Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792 "(null)"}}

Important key points:

1. This issue occurs only for IOS devices.
2. It happens on old devices.
3. The file is not corrupted.
4. When trying to load multiple thumbnails from the same URL, some are loaded while others getting the error.
5. I tried to uninstall and rebuild the app again but nothing worked.
6. There is no problem on Android devices.

Comment: Try providing thumbnailPath argument as described on the package page https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail - Generate a thumbnail file from video URL

Comment: Facing the same issue for `VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your platform configuration has appropriate permissions to make network requests and download/store images.